# Cant access NSString outside of the viewdidload

Tags: ios6, nsstring, nsarray

I have a `NSString` declared in .h file. Then I assign a value inside the `ViewDidload`. In my `didSelectRowatIndex` event wants to assign that value to an another string in previous Viewcontroller.

.h

`

```
 NSString *strWifiId;

 NSArray *arrstrWifiId;`
```

`
      - (void)viewDidLoad
     {

```
        arrstrWifiId=[arrWorkflow valueForKey:@"WFID"];

        strWifiId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrstrWifiId objectAtIndex:0] ];
 }
```

`

`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

NSLog(@"navi array count ----- %d",[array count]);


UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];




for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {


    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SendTimeChangeRequestViewController class]] ) {


        SendTimeChangeRequestViewController *groupViewController = (SendTimeChangeRequestViewController*)viewController;


        [groupViewController.btnwrkflwFirstApprove setTitle:selectedCell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        groupViewController.pWorkFlowID=strWifiId;

        NSLog(@"WFID---- %@",groupViewController.pWorkFlowID);
        //NSLog(@"CELL TAG----- %@",groupViewController.pAuthEmployeeCode);


        [self.navigationController popToViewController:groupViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

`

here that `NSLog` prints some garbage value. Why is that n how can I solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You own the object returned from `initWithFormat` which you are responsible for releasing, but you don't own the object returned from `stringWithFormat` which returns an autoreleased string and so do not need to release it (if you do want to have ownership of it, you must retain it).

So for resolving your issue try to assign your value like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

        arrstrWifiId=[arrWorkflow valueForKey:@"WFID"];

        strWifiId=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[arrstrWifiId objectAtIndex:0] ];
 }
```